# How can I compute this definite integral?

Tags: integration, improper-integrals

How to compute

$$\int_0^1\frac1{1-x^n}dx\;,$$

where $n>0$?

Answer (score 5):

Since $x^n \leq x$ in $[0,1]$, $$\int^1_0 \frac{1}{1-x^n} dx \geq \int^1_0 \frac{1}{1-x} dx$$ and the right integral is divergent. So your integral diverges.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott I sure did! Feel free to edit such mistakes if you see me make them again =].

Comment: Okay; will do!$\;$

Comment: @RagibZaman I liked the first direction better.

Comment: @RagibZaman Maybe I am not clear enough: The current direction of the inequality is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Note that

$$\frac 1 {1-x^n} = \frac 1 {n(1-x)} +f(x)$$

for a function $f(x)$ that is continuous in the interval $[0,1]$, so the improper integral will exist for all $n \ge 1$ if and only if it exists for $n=1$.

But for $n=1$ you have an explicit antiderivative (using the logarithm), and you can check that it tends to infinity if you let the upper limit of the integral go to 1.